# Why is GNU libstdc++ coupled to gcc and GNU libc not?

Tags: gcc, glibc, libstdc++

The concrete reason I am asking this, is because I am trying to produce a C/C++ toolchain that can build C++17 code and produce binaries that can run on as many client systems as possible. I need at least gcc 9 for (stable) C++17 support. But that would mean the client system needs at least libstdc++.so.6.0.26 (GLIBCXX_3.4.26). It would also mean I cannot use a newer compiler without losing compatibility with several client systems, because libstdc++ is coupled to gcc.

GNU libc is not coupled to gcc. I can choose the newest compiler and still use the old glibc 2.28 to build C11 code.

Comment: I don't know the answer but I suggest statically linking both of those libraries so you don't have to worry about what version is installed on the client system.  https://github.com/DavidEGrayson/nixcrpkgs

Comment: GNU libc is so much more than the standard C library, it's the whole system-call interface to the Linux system, and more. It's *also* not the actual full C library, much of it is supplied by GCC itself. As for the standard C++ library, it has always been closely tied to the compiler, and that tight coupling is not unique to GCC and libstdc++, it's for all C++ compilers. The only compiler where that rule is broken is for Clang, which can use the GNU libstdc++, if it's installed.

Comment: @David Grayson: Static linking with GNU libc[++] is not an option, our code uses `dlopen()`. Your link points to musl libc. I opted that a viable solution, but managers often do not prefer unconventional solutions.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is GNU libstdc++ coupled to gcc and GNU libc not?

`libstdc++` is *not really* coupled to GCC either -- you *can* use `g++` to build `C++` code with `libc++` instead.

*By default* `g++` uses `libstdc++` because they both come from the same project, while GLIBC is a separate project.

Comment: One of the developers of gcc and GNU libstdc++ writes "The version of libstdc++ is tightly coupled to the version of GCC" in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52879013/7268445

Comment: @Bart "The version of libstdc++ is tightly coupled to the version of GCC" -- that is correct but in no way contradicts my answer. You can't use old GCC with new `libstdc++` or vice versa, but you can sure use GCC _without_ `libstdc++`.

Comment: If gcc and libstdc++ are decoupled, then why is not possible/easy to use a new C++17 compliant gcc (say gcc12) with an old C++17 compliant GNU libstdc++ (say libstdc++.so.6.0.26)?

Comment: @Bart They are not decoupled, they are version-locked together. That is, _IFF_ you use `libstdc++`, then you _must_ use the version matching your GCC. But you are not forced to use `libstdc++`, you can use an alternate library (provided that library supports your version of GCC).

Comment: +1 for making that clear. Although I still cease to see the reason why to version-lock libstdc++ to gcc but not to version-lock libc to gcc.