Building with new version of compiler and old libc / libstdc++
I'm trying to build a Tensorflow Lite library for armhf, basically following the steps here. To preserve backwards compatibility of the library we ship, we want libc / libstdc++ version to remain unchanged. Tensorflow lite had ARM toolchain version bumped in this PR.
The interesting thing is that it was done because the compiler needed a version bump and not libc / libstdc++, which is normally bundled with the compiler in an embedded toolchain.
I was successful in building Tensorflow Lite library for aarch64 - this was done natively, without cross-compilation tools. However, I can not do it in a similar way for armhf, building also natively on Raspberry Pi 4 (Buster). I built and installed 11.x version of GCC compiler on Raspberry Pi. There is also old libc / libstdc++ in the system. What I am stuck at now is new compiler using libstdc++ bundled with it.
I can provide more details about exact build environment, but my main question is: how does one build with new version of compiler and old libc / libstdc++ with cmake?
I'd assume there would be certain flags, which would set the compiler path and also path to look for libc / libstdc++ headers/libs. But perhaps my assumption is wrong.

I'm not sure if you can make GCC use a different version of libstdc++, but Clang lets you use any libstdc++ installation.

It's not possible with gcc (according to one of the main gcc maintainers) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454930/forcing-g-gcc-to-a-specific-libstdc-version-glibcxx
